# Mockito - mock for Context and getApplicationContext()

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

Just started creating UTs for my app and using PowerMock, Mockito and Junit4.
Im having a very fundamental problem of mocking Context and getApplicationContext(). I cant seem to understand how to do that.

What i tried so far is the following :

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mContext = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
    Mockito.when(mContext.getApplicationContext()).thenReturn(mContext);

    PowerMockito.whenNew(IabHelper.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(new IabHelperMock(mContext, null));
}
```

Everything runs ok when im using debugger (Android Studio) and pausing over the below line, but when i run the test without debugger the test fails (because of the same line) :

```
public IabHelper(Context ctx, String base64PublicKey) {
    mContext = ctx.getApplicationContext();
    ...
}
```

The failure message im getting is :

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
>   Unfinished stubbing detected here:
>   -> at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.invocation.MockitoNewInvocationControl.expectSubstitutionLogic(MockitoNewInvocationControl.java:65)
>   E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
>   Examples of correct stubbing:
>       when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
>       when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
>       doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
>   Hints:
>    1. missing thenReturn()
>    2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
>    3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed
>       at com.xxx.libs.components.purchase.util.IabHelper.(IabHelper.java:164)
>       at com.xxx.libs.mocks.IabHelperMock.(IabHelperMock.java:22)
>   ...

Im clearly doing something wrong and i would like to know what exactly. What is the best practice for using Context and getApplicationContext() ?
Thanks.

Comment: Please, provide us with more details like chunks of the class you are testing and your testing method. I don't really understand this, though: `Mockito.when(mContext.getApplicationContext()).thenReturn(mContext);`, do you really want to return the mock itself?

Comment: I want to return a Context object, when using Context directly, or when getting it by calling getApplicationContext(). Not sure if this the way of doing that using Mockito and Junit4, but that's why i asked for a best practice. Regarding your "more details" request - the class holds @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) and @PrepareForTest annotations for some tested classes and the testing method doesnt really have anything relevant besides one method call which eventually created the above IabHelper instance. btw, IabHelperMock constructor is calling the super (IabHelper).